# How can I scroll an entire page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to always scroll up or down an entire page ($(window).height) when using the scroll bar or the mouse.

I've already tried a few things, but in the code displayed I always scroll to the end of the document

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = parseInt($(this).scrollTop());
        var hg = parseInt($(window).height());
        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            $(document).scrollTop(st + hg);
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like a horrible UX.   The scroll bar is directly linked to the scroll position, so if you change one it changes the other.  You would need to disassociate the actual content from the scrollable content and then manage the position of the actual content as a percentage/div() of the scroll position

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and code, it seems that you want the page to scroll directly to the top or bottom on scroll. Here is a sample code that you can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Direct Section Scroll</title>
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var scrolling = false;

            // Adding event listener with { passive: false } to avoid the 
            passive event listener warning
            window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default scrolling

                if (!scrolling) {
                    scrolling = true;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        scrolling = false;
                    }, 800);
                    var scrollAmount = $(window).height();
                    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
                        // Scrolling up
                        $("html").stop().animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, 600);
                    } else {
                        // Scrolling down
                        $("html").stop().animate({
                            scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
                        }, 600);
                    }
                }
            }, { passive: false });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        section {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        #section1 {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        #section2 {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        #section3 {
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section1">
        Section 1
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
        Section 2
    </section>
    <section id="section3">
        Section 3
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*scroll up or down an entire page ($(window).height)*" - would indicate a page at a time rather than top/bottom

Answer (score 0):

To achieve scrolling in two directions (up and down) you need to update your code, here is an example:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var hg = $(window).height();

    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        // Scrolling down
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: '+=' + hg
        }, 100);
    } else {
        // Scrolling up
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: '-=' + hg
        }, 100);
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.content {
    height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll Page Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```